# Why is the step length by default equal to 1 in gradient boosting?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, boosting

On ESL p.359, it explains steepest descent:
[image]
[image]

But in 10.37, it is trying to minimize the distance to g_im. It looks like the default step length is 1. Why is it so?
[image]

Comment: It looks like 10.37 is describing fitting a base model (e.g regression tree) to the gradient by minimizing the squared error. Step length is not involved at all here.

Comment: Gotcha. Is the step length similar to learning rate?

Comment: In the context of general, gradient-based optimization algorithms, step size and learning rate refer to the same thing. In gradient boosting, we sometimes multiply the optimal step size by a fraction to shrink it (providing regularization). In this context, the multiplicative factor is often called the learning rate.

Comment: ESL did not talk about how to calculate the optimal step size - on page.361, I think Algorithm 10.3 sets the step length to be 1. After calculating this, on page 364, formula 10.41 includes a learning rate v to shrink the step length 1. In this case, the learning rate v serves as a hyper-parameter to approximate the optimal step length.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your last comment regarding algorithm 10.3 is correct. Finding the optimal value for each leaf node is like running a separate line search for each leaf node (so each gets its own step size)